# How can I update pages that live in a specific folder?

Tags: powershell

Via PowerShell, I would like to edit the page layout of all the publishing pages that live within a specific folder (or any subfolders of that folder) in the Pages library.  I found this script that gets me most of the way there but I have no clue how filter based on folder.

```
$SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("http://currentsitename/webname")
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("http://currentsitename/webname/Pages/Test-Page.aspx")
$spFile.CheckOut("Online",$null)
$spFile.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Block.aspx, Block"
$spFile.Update()
$spFile.CheckIn("Update page layout via PowerShell", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
```

This only has to be run one time, I'm not opposed to using a console application instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$folder = $spWeb.GetFolder($path);

 $sItems = $folder.folder.Files

 if($folder.Folder.Files.count -gt 0) 
 { 
        foreach($item in $sItems) 
        {

              $SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
              $item.CheckOut("Online",$null)
              $item.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Block.aspx, Block"
              $item.Update()
              $item.CheckIn("Update page layout via PowerShell", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
              Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment

        }
 }
```

For sub-folders inside the folder, you may need to apply recursive operation!

I haven't tried this, but this should work! You may need to modify at some places...